# Attributes get stripped from iframe tag

Tags: javascript, wysihtml5

I want to use an iframe in my content using wysihtml5-0.4.0pre, I added

```
"iframe": {
  "remove": 0
}
```

to my parserRules and the iframe tag is passed, but with all attributes (src, width, height etc.) stripped. Where does this happen and what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to whitelist the attributes. Adding the following to your parser rules should do the trick (it will set the width and hight and allow a valid src):

```
"iframe": {
  "check_attributes": {
     "src": "url"
  },
  "set_attributes": {
      "width": "560",
      "height": "315",
      "frameborder": "0"
  }
}
```